# how can i add a for loop to stop infinite loop

Tags: javascript, api, for-loop, infinite-loop

i want to make this code keep trying after getting an error for like 10 times after the 10 times it should stop trying and instead of trying it will show a message instead that there is something wrong ,
so i threw an error there on purpose to make it give errors and a for loop but instead it keeps trying in separate error messages as shown in the pic below , so how can i add that for loop so it can stop trying running the function and show a message instead ?

[image]

this is my code :

```
async function getQuote() {
loading();

const apiUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/? 
method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en';
try {

const response = await fetch(apiUrl) 
const data = await response.json();

// Changing the blank Author textfield to Unknown
if (data.quoteAuthor === ''){
    authorText.innerText = 'Unknown';
} else {
    authorText.innerText = data.quoteAuthor;
}
if (quoteText.innerText.length > 120){
    quoteText.classList.add('long-quote');
} else {
    quoteText.classList.remove('long-quote');
}
quoteText.innerText = data.quoteText

//Stop loader, Show Quote
complete();

throw new Error("Opss!")
} catch(error) { 
for(let i=0; i < 10 ; i++){
    getQuote();
    // console.log('something went wrong!', error);
 }
}
}
```

Comment: This does it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-retry

If you can't bundle it, you can examine the source code and replicate it. It's pretty simple machinery.

You need to make your function return a Promise.

Comment: @Adamazad Thank you for your suggestions , its really helpful but i would like to know the traditional through JS using for loop

Answer (score 0):

you can try building a global variable that counts the number of errors and breaks out of the loop at a certain number

```
async function getQuote(numOfTries = 1) {
  try {
    ...

    throw new Error("Opss!")
  }
  catch (error) {
    if (numOfTries === 10) {
      console.log('something went wrong!', error);
    } else {
      numOfTries++;
      getQuote(numOfTries);
    }
  }
}
```